# Open Source Java PDF Viewers that can play embedded media

Tags: java, pdf, open-source

I'm trying to find a open source pdf viewer that I can embed in a java swing application.  The PDFs will have embedded media in them so I will need the viewer to be able to play the media.  Does anyone know of any good pdf viewers?

I've tried ICEpdf, JPedal and Pdf Renderer but playing the embedded media in all of them was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Have a look at this blog](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-opensourcejava-pdf-renderer.html)

> Open source Java projects: SwingLabs PDF Renderer

Answer (score 0):

The media would need a Java library capable of playing the embedded media. That is why we do not support things like 3D walk-throughs in JPedal because cannot find a library which can support them. If the library exists, we could all add the support.